# Android show alert dialog on bottom right, and use activity while it is shown

Tags: java, android, android-activity, dialog

I'm trying to show a dialog. But I want it to be at bottom right of the view and I want to use the activity while the dialog is staying there. How can I solve it out ?

This is what I get

[image: Actual Result]

This is what I want

[image: Wanted result]

And this is my DialogFragment class if necessary :

```html
    
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Test")
                .setPositiveButton("Fire", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Comment: I don't think you should go with the dialog, make a view with text and buttons and position it at the bottom right. Dialog pauses your activity until action is taken.

Comment: @BojanKseneman Good solution, but I have more than one activity in my project and adding text and buttons to each of them will be really hard.

Comment: you colud then use PopupWindow [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html]. You can set it's position to where ever you want it. Google for examples, i'm sure there is a ton of them.

Comment: @BojanKseneman That is what I am exactly looking for ! Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found it out. Thanks to @Bojan Kseneman

> you could use PopupWindow. You can set it's position to where ever you want it. Google for examples, i'm sure there is a ton of them.

I found this : http://android-er.blogspot.com.tr/2012/03/example-of-using-popupwindow.html

And it works like a charm !
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1hhm.png

The good thing is, you can edit the popup ! It's a layout !

Thanks to @Bojan Kseneman again. You saved me from a lot of work.